# Best distributed filesystem for commodity linux storage farm

Tags: linux, filesystems, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I have a lot of spare intel linux servers laying around (hundreds) and want to use them for a distributed file system in a web hosting and file sharing environment.  This isn't for a HPC application, so high performance isn't critical.  The main requirement is high availability, if one server goes offline, the data stored on it's hard drives is still available from other nodes.  It must run over TCP/IP and provide standard POSIX file permissions.

I've looked at the following:

- Lustre (http://wiki.lustre.org/index.php?title=Main_Page):  Comes *really* close, but it doesn't provide redundancy for data on a node.  You must make the data HA using RAID or DRBD.  Supported by Sun and Open Source, so it should be around for a while
- gfarm (http://datafarm.apgrid.org/): Looks like it provides the redundancy but at the cost of complexity and maintainability.  Not as well supported as Lustre.

Does anyone have any experience with these or any other systems that might work?

Comment: Would you like to share us your final decision on it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

check also [GlusterFS](http://www.gluster.org/)

**Edit (Aug-2012):** [Ceph](http://ceph.com/) is finally getting ready.  Recently the authors formed [Inktank](http://www.inktank.com/), an independent company to sell commercial support for it.  According to some presentaions, the mountable POSIX-compliant filesystem is the uppermost layer and  not really tested yet, but the lower layers are being used in production for some time now.

The interesting part is the RADOS layer, which presents an object-based storage with both a 'native' access via the `librados` library (available for several languages) and an Amazon S3-compatible RESP API.  Either one makes it more than adequate for adding massive storage to a web service.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXcZ2bnnGZg) is a good description of the philosophy, architecture, capabilities and current status.

Comment: I was disappointed by glusterfs performance / reliability under heavy IO loads.

Comment: Can you please share what "heavy IO loads" mean? how many IOPS?

Comment: What happens if a node falls out? I'm curious about a "gluster" like setup, where the cluster can contribute data (for redundancy, or for additional storage, at the server's choice), and disconnect whenever it wants without destroying the "raid array".

Comment: Having used it extensively, I would describe the POSIX filesystem layer of ceph as experimental and horribly buggy, FYI.

Comment: @PaulWheeler: I concur.  what i wanted to note is that other non-fs-like layers (RADOS, rdb) are getting quite reliable.  For POSIX compatibility, it seems MooseFS is much better.  I'd love to see ceph-fs mature, since rdb is quite desirable to have in the same cluster...

Comment: IMHO Ceph is nowhere near to be ready and certainly not going to become ready in the nearby future. I recommend to avoid Ceph as it have too many issues to be used with reasonable degree of confidence.

Comment: I also had a pretty bad experience with glusterfs during heavy IO load, some times the server would crash, and the files starts disappearing.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, the best file system for Linux is MooseFS , it's quite new, but I had an opportunity to compare it with Ceph and Lustre and I say for sure that MooseFS is the best one.

Comment: Agreed with correction: MooseFS is now proprietary so its successor [LizardFS](http://lizardfs.org) is the best IMHO.

Comment: @Onlyjob - MooseFS is no longer proprietary

Comment: Technically speaking. But it does not have public VCS nor bug tracker. What if author take down source archive and provide it by request *again*? LizardFS already has community behind it and (unlike MooseFS) LizardFS will be in Debian soon. LizardFS is unrestricted (i.e. no "community edition" etc.).

Comment: MooseFS source code is available on GitHub: https://github.com/moosefs/moosefs

Answer (score 4):

Gluster is getting quite a lot of press at the moment:

http://www.gluster.org/

Comment: @dpavlin - does it matter if it's a duplicate? Yes, the answerer shouldn't have added it since it was already there, but downvoting just because it's a duplicate seems wrong

Comment: Glusterfs is fat, eats lots of memory during high IO load, and very slow.

Answer (score 2):

Lustre has been working for us.  It's not perfect but it's the only thing we have tried that has not broken down over load.  We still get LBUGS from time to time and dealing with 100TB + file systems is never easy but the Lustre system has worked and increased both performance and availability.

Answer (score 2):

If not someone forces you to use it, I would also highly recommend using anything else than Lustre. From what I hear from others and what also gave myself nightmares for quite some time is the fact that Lustre quite easily breaks down in all kinds of situations. And if only a single client in the system breaks down, it puts itself into an endless do_nothing_loop mode typically while holding some important global lock - so the next time another client tries to access the same information, it will also hang. Thus, you often end up rebooting the whole cluster, which I guess is something you would try to avoid normally ;)

Modern parallel file systems like FhGFS (http://www.fhgfs.com) are way more robust here and also allow you to do nice things like running server and client components on the same machines (though built-in HA features are still under development, as someone from their team told me, but their implementation is going to be pretty awesome from what I've heard).

Comment: fhghfs, from the people who gave us the mp3 patent?

Answer (score 0):

[Ceph](http://ceph.newdream.net/) looks to be a promising new-ish entry into the arena. The site claims it's not ready for production use yet though.

Comment: Experience confirms such claim.

Answer (score 0):

I read a lot about distributed filesystems and I think FhGFS is the best.

http://www.fhgfs.com/

It worth a try. See more about it at:

http://www.fhgfs.com/wiki/

Comment: FhGFS is a proprietary software without sources. Don't waste everyone's time please. -1.